# Multiple socket connections without re-opening a new socket each time

Tags: python

I have a small web app that will invoke python scripts each time a user clicks on a button.

Each time someone clicks the button, I open the socket connection, connect, do what I have to do and close the connection.

After every socket connection, the telnet server generates a ton of events and there is no way for me to modify the telnet server.

Is there any way to have the button always connect to the same socket connection so that I don't have to see all those events generated? Basically only see these events on the first connection. Code is below. I was thinking of having a py script running in the background with an open connection and just have my code below connect to socket that py script is using in the background

```
 clientsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
 clientsocket.connect((127.0.0.1, 11111))

 clientsocket.send('test\r\n')
 connection = clientsocket.recv(buf)

 close_connection(clientsocket,buf)
```

Comment: Yes it's possible. Use the same connection (as some kind of a *Singleton*), don't close it. However, if multiple clients share it in parallel, you are / might be in trouble. But the (apparent) end goal ("*so that I don't have to see all those events*") seams silly (at least). Just reduce server verbosity.

Comment: Thanks. Yes multiple clients will share it in parallel. The server guys will not be making any changes so I am stuck with what they give me. Basically, their server handles each connection as a new session, so that's  the reason why all the events get generated becuase each connection is a new session to the server. Is there any for me to make these multuple parallel connections as the same session?